# Copy data from a particular column of a table to a particular column in an empty table in sql server

Tags: sql, insert

Can anyone help me with this?
I have two tables with different columns,just one column is same for both tables. I want to copy data from a particular column of the source table to a particular column in the target table in sql.

I found that update statement will work if there is some data in the table but it is not working as my target table is empty.

I tried insert into target( col)
Select col from source where condition.

But it gives cannot insert null value error

Comment: Add more details. Which tables, what query, what schema?

Comment: What is your DBMS? What is the exact error message? Doesn't the DBMS tell you which column must not be null? Is it the one you are inserting? Then add `and col is not null` to your condition. If it is another column, then what value do you want to insert into that other column?

Comment: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/388759/why-should-i-tag-my-rdbms

Answer (score 1):

If you want to copy data from one table to another in SQL, including copying data from a particular column in the source table to a particular column in the target table, you should ensure that the target table has the necessary structure (columns) to receive the data. If the target table is empty and you're getting a "cannot insert null value" error, it may be due to the source column having NULL values.

If you're encountering NULL value errors, you can use the COALESCE function to handle NULL values or use a WHERE clause to filter out rows with NULL values in the source column.

```
INSERT INTO target_table (target_column)
SELECT COALESCE(source_column, 'default_value_if_null')
FROM source_table;
```

or

```
INSERT INTO target_table (target_column)
SELECT source_column
FROM source_table
WHERE source_column IS NOT NULL;
```

Comment: Both WHERE clause IS NULL and COALESCE?

Answer (score 0):

I am writing the below query but it gives error: conversion failed when converting the varchar value 'wosworkschedule' to data type int.

The thing is there is no column as wosworkschedule in any of the tables. My query is as follows

```
INSERT INTO target(a,b,c,d)
SELECT
    a1, b1, (SELECT MAX(c) + 1 FROM target), (SELECT(MAX(d) + 1 FROM target)
FROM
    source
WHERE
    b1 IS NOT NULL
```